# I'm having trouble reading data from a sqlite file in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and the problem seems to be that the if statement at the bottom of the following code is failing:

```
sqlite3 *database;
if (sqlite3_open([[self dataFilePath] UTF8String], &database)
    != SQLITE_OK) { 

    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
}
else 
    NSLog(@"Database opened successfully");

//CREATE THE TABLE HERE IF NEEDED

NSString *createSQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workouts "" (ROW INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, FIELD_DATA TEXT);";
char *errorMsg;
if (sqlite3_exec(database, [createSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK) { sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert(0, @"Error creating table: %s", errorMsg);
}

sqlite3_stmt *statement;


if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String],
                       -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
```

What could be the problem?  I know there are a lot of other factors involved, but anything would be helpful.  Just ask if you want any additional info.  Thanks StackOverflow!

edit: the error that i'm receiving is:     no such column: columnName

Comment: Can you put all the console logs that you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I wouldn't recreate any part of the Core Data framework unless you have a very good reason to do so. This tutorial might help you get started with Core Data programming
http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Here's the reference page for Core Data:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650